# How to manage memory when load more and more images at a time using AsyncImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, asynchronous, imageview

Please give solution about how can i load multiple images from URL at a time using AsyncImageView? because there is some memory issues appear when images load. and there is more than 500 images come form web service

It's my code:

```
Maindict in 500 record

CGSize viewwidth=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
int size = (viewwidth.width/3)-10;
float x=(viewwidth.width-(size*3))/4;
float y=(viewwidth.width-(size*3))/4;

for (int i=0; i<Maindict.count; i++)
{
    AsyncImageView *Galleryimg = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,size,size)];
    Galleryimg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    Galleryimg.clipsToBounds=YES;
    Galleryimg.tag=i;
    Galleryimg.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[[[Maindict valueForKey:@"image"]objectAtIndex:i]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [scroll addSubview:Galleryimg];
    if((i+1)%3==0 && i!=0)
    {
        y=y+(size+(viewwidth.width-(size*3))/4);
        x=(viewwidth.width-(size*3))/4;
    }
    else
    {
        x=x+(size+(viewwidth.width-(size*3))/4);
    }
}
scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(viewwidth.width,y+(size+(viewwidth.width-(size*3))/4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You create 500 images at one time. I think you should create image when you need to display or use it.

You can detect when display rect is near with image position, and create image at that time.

Just idea but hope it help

Answer (score -1):

trying to load 500+ images at the same time on a mobile device is very bad idea. it will drain device's battery quickly. and you will receive lots of low memory warnings. you need to lazy load images.

i see you are already using scrollview to display those images. instead of a scrollview you should use a tableview or collection view. they are also subclasses of scrollview. you should start downloading images on a cell in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method of uitableview's data source.

Comment: Adem Ozgur  Are you sure?

Comment: as i described in my answer you should start downloading images asynchronously in the delegate method of tableview or collection view. checkout Examples of https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage